# How to make ollydbg to open on default openning the main code

Tags: ollydbg

The program does not start from the main code. always start from the title [CPU - main thread, module ntdll]. It takes a lot of time to get the ollydbg showing the right main code.[Here we can the wrong situation.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uAaN1.png)

[This is the right way I look for.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uuW5z.png)

thank you very much!

Comment: it stops and displays simply where the assembly execution halted. you can cycle your code, set breakpoints or navigate through the executable modules manually or set breakpoints and bookmarks where you need them. but don't except registers to show proper values for code that is not currently in execution. that is not how assembler works.

Comment: You can as well search through code but it does not make much sense to display the main module entry point while it is not currently being executed. To archieve that, you have to set a breakpoint there.